# django-admin throws syntax error - configuration issue I think

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly green in Python and trying to get django working to build a simple website. I've installed Django 1.6 under Python 2.7.6 but can't get django-admin to run. According to the tutorial I should create a project as follows, but I get a syntax error:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> import sys
>>> print(django.VERSION)
(1, 6, 0, 'final', 0)
>>> django-admin.py startproject Nutana
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    django-admin.py startproject Nutana
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I've created a .pth file in the site-packages directory with this:

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\bin
```

but that doesn't help. I've tried it with relative paths as well, and with the slashes going the other way.

I've also tried straight from the command line:

```
Z:\Nutana GeophysicsXXX\Web_Django>python django-admin.py startproject Nutana
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Where have I gone wrong??

Comment: `django-admin` should be run in the command line, and not in the django shell. Now, have you forgotten to activate a virtualenv if you are using ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
django-admin.py startproject Nutana
```

should be run in the command line, and not in the django shell.

If the second case is not working

1. If you are using a virtual-env, did you forget to activate it ?
2. Make sure you add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to the path, and you would not face this issue.

Comment: adding Scripts to the path did the trick. Not sure what you mean by virtual-env, I'll have to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `$ django-admin.py startproject mysite`

You don't need the python statement in front.

Comment: This wont help fixing the issue.

Comment: just curious as to why not?

Comment: Try it out.. The issue is with the path.