# Django Tutorial Problems

Tags: python, django

I am just starting with Django and am trying to do the tutorial. The first step in the tutorial is to set the current directory to a folder where you want to save the code you are writing then, in the command window, execute the python command django-admin.py startproject name. For some reason I continually get a syntax error with the carrot under the last t in startproject when running the command. I have also tried running django-admin.py help and that also doesn't work. I am sure Django downloaded properly. I ensured the django-admin folder was in the right directory (under bin) as well as ensured that I installed the proper versions of both Django and Python for compatibility. Any ideas?
As always, thanks.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553695/django-admin-throws-syntax-error-configuration-issue-i-think) - are you trying to run the command in the Python shell? It should be run from the command line.

Comment: I'm running it from the cmd

Comment: Can you post the full command input and output?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jackf_000>cd PythonCodes

C:\Users\jackf_000\PythonCodes>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> django-admin.py startproject mysite
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    django-admin.py startproject mysite
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: sorry if it looks ugly. I dont know how to add code to comments like you can in the question

Comment: I'm afraid you should not run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` in your python interpreter.

Comment: You are inside your python interpreter...just run it on regular console with something like python django-admin.py startproject mysite (assuming you are in the folder of the django-admin and that python is in path)

Comment: right, i was. thanks